# Loading images in WKWebView on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, wkwebview

I have a macOS application that allows the user to select markdown files thru NSOpenPanel.

```
let mdUrl = openPanel.urls.first!
let baseUrl = mdUrl.deletingLastPathComponent()
let md = try! String(contentsOf: mdUrl)
let html = try! Down(markdownString: md).toHTML()
webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: baseUrl)
```

The problem is that the images located in a Images-folder at the same level as the selected md-file are not beeing loaded. Here is an example of the html-beeing loaded by the webView:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p><img src="Images/Exampleimage.png" alt="" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The baseUrl contains an Images-directory with the specified image. What should I do to get the images to load and display properly?

Answer (score 1):

In that case you have to represent image as Base64 String, try below code

```
    func getImageString(imageLocalPath: String) -> String? {

        //get UIImage from localPath
        let image:UIImage = // some method
        if let _image = image {
          // assume image is png, if not use relevant constrauction
          var data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_image)!

          if let _data = data {
            let data64 = _data.base64EncodedString(options:
                Data.Base64EncodingOptions.endLineWithCarriageReturn)
            return "<img src='data:image/\(format);base64," + data64 + "' height=200 width=400>"
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Add the strig of image as follows, then it should appear

```
var data64 = getImageString(//image_local path)

"<img src='data:image/\(format);base64," + data64 + "' height=200 width=400>"
```

Comment: I'm trying to load images that are relative to the md-file beeing opened. If I open a file .../RootFolder/Test.md and there is .../RootFolder/Images/Exampleimage.png the relative path in the given tag is already pointing to the correct location??

Comment: Are you trying to show local image in the webView ??

Comment: If you just create a Index.html file and create a Images-folder with images in the same directory and open the Index.html that contains image-tags referencing images in the Images-folder in any browser, the images will show. WKWebView is not showing those images.

Comment: Is there really no sane way to have the images load just as they do in any normal browser? Why won't plane old html work?

Comment: Its possible to load in plane old html way, if you put the image and html file both in a folder in project. Just create folder in the xcode project and put image and html . Then p><img src="Images/Exampleimage.png" alt="" /></p> should work

Comment: That doesn't work as the app is intended for viewing markdown-files generated by the user and which can reside anywhere on disk